# How to reload tableView after dismissing a UIViewController

Tags: ios, tableview, reloaddata

I use the following method to present a UIViewController named DictAddSubSecondCell:

```
// UIViewControler 1
- (IBAction)addWord:(id)sender{
dictAddSubSecondCellController = [[DictAddSubSecondCell alloc] initWithNibName:@"DictAddSubSecondCell" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:dictAddSubSecondCellController animated:YES];
[dictAddSubSecondCellController release];
}
```

and when I click the button in DictAddSubSecondCell:

```
- (IBAction)dismissAction:(id)sender{ 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

the tableView at UIViewControler 1 didn't reload it's data, but I added a method in viewWillApear method:

```
[self.table reloadData];
```

but it still not work. I have no idea about this. Is there any suggestions for me? thanks.

Here is the full source code of UIViewcontroller 1:

```
//
//  DictAddSubSecond.m
//
//  Created by Samuel Armstrong on 4/8/12.
//  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DictAddSubSecond.h"
#import "DictionaryList.h"

@implementation DictAddSubSecond
@synthesize dictList, table, editButton;
@synthesize dictAddSubSecondCellController;

- (IBAction)addWord:(id)sender
{
    dictAddSubSecondCellController = [[DictAddSubSecondCell alloc] initWithNibName:@"DictAddSubSecondCell" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:dictAddSubSecondCellController animated:YES];
    [dictAddSubSecondCellController release];
}

- (IBAction)toggleEdit {
    [self.table setEditing:!self.table.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.table.editing) {
        [editButton setTitle:@"Done"];
        [editButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
    }
    else {
        [editButton setTitle:@"Edit"];
        [editButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];

    }
}

- (IBAction)dismissAction:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)refreshTableData
{
    NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *file = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dictWithWords.tmp"];
    if (dictList == nil) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file];
        if ([array objectAtIndex:0] != nil) {
            dictList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
            self.dictList = array;
            [array release];
        }
        else
        {
            dictList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        }
    }
    [self.table reloadData];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self refreshTableData];
}

- (void)someMethodToReloadTable:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    [table reloadData];  
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethodToReloadTable) name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];


}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [dictList count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MoveMeCellIdentifier = @"MoveMeCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MoveMeCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MoveMeCellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //A Boolean value that determines whether the cell shows the reordering control.
        cell.showsReorderControl = YES;

    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [dictList objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    [self.dictList removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
}


- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}




// Asks the data source whether a given row can be moved to another location in the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}


//Tells the data source to move a row at a specific location in the table view to another location.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSUInteger fromRow = [fromIndexPath row];
    NSUInteger toRow = [toIndexPath row];

    id object = [[dictList objectAtIndex:fromRow] retain];
    [dictList removeObjectAtIndex:fromRow];
    [dictList insertObject:object atIndex:toRow];
    [object release];
}


@end
```

Comment: The logic seems reasonable.  Can you use either log messages or the debugger to check two things: is `[self.table reloadData]` actually being called there and, if it is, do you see any calls after that to your delegate methods (such as `numberOfRowsInSection:`)?

Comment: I modified a file (a NSArray instance using writeTOfile method) in Documents/ folder in DictAddSubSecondCell, and I want to show the modified results in UIViewControler 1.

I can only see the new result by reloading UIViewControler 1 now.

Comment: Which means TableView not reloading after modalview dismissed

Answer (score 1):

Try calling it in `viewDidAppear:` instead of `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Are you sure that viewDidAppear: is getting called? Put an NSLog statement inside it to make sure. It's easy to mistype the delegate method and it has to be exact to be called.

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated is called when I dismiss.

Comment: Then maybe the new data hasn't been added to your model properly. Check the data using a log statement when you return to the first view controller.

Comment: Problem solved!
Although I linked the delegate and datasource to its file owner, it looks like not working, so I added self.table.delegate = self;  && self.table.datasource = self; in viewDidLoad method, and it's gonna work fine.!